# How to show the dynamic data in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

I wanted to create infinite scroll in angular 2 using javascript code(It's weird to use javascript but it is working fine). I am able to create infinite static html. 
But i wanted to push the dynamic data which comes from service to this innerHtml.
Following is simple javascript code.

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
    this.yHandler(); 
}
public yHandler() {
    this.numberincrem++;
    console.log(this.numberincrem);
    var Title = this.PostTitle;
    console.log(Title);
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
    var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if (y >= contentHeight) {

        wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">{{Title}}</div>';
    }
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = contentHeight + " | " + y;
}
```

It is showing

> {{Title}}

in the html but in console i am able to see the value of Title.

plz help

Comment: Adding HTML code with `document.getElementById` is absolutely not how Angular works.

Comment: have you tried to compile? or apply?

Comment: He should try to understand Angular first, instead of compiling HTML templates added with `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes i can see the title in console. But it is not getting render in html.

Comment: `{{Title}}` this means you should have some fatal error in console... Angular isn't working

Comment: @C.jacking, you have a mistake between console, title, and apply from angular

Comment: yes may be but how i can show the dynamic data to html using innerHtml.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i didn't get your point.

Comment: yes, you are using {{}}, in javascript, so you need to make an apply of your scope, for make angular draw the var in your view

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón how can i do that? any example

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón thanks but example in based on angularjs not angular 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use [interpolate string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Like so `` wrap.innerHTML += `<div class="newData">${Title}</div>`; ``

Comment: it didn't help me it is still showing me ${Title} in html

Comment: Are you sure you are using -> ` , not -> '

Comment: This is not an angular answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the quote character from `'` to " ` ", and use the variable ${Title} like this:

```
wrap.innerHTML += `<div class="newData">${Title}</div>`;
```

Just like the answer of Biser Atanasov above, I just note to sure you don't miss the quote updating.

or you can cut the string and merge it after adding the variable, like this:

```
wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">' + Title + '</div>';
```

Comment: This is not an angular answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just the value of Title before changing your view? Something like :

`wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData">' + Title + '</div>';`

Of course, you won't be able to change it dynamically. But that is how you decided to do it by using `document.getElementById`...

Comment: This is not an angular answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change directly on an element innerHtml, if you are going to do so, don't use Angular 2, calling `document` object and changing innerHtml will definitely break server side rendering on your application and the change detection will not be able to apply the new changes that you added using innerHtml.

make sure to read this:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

instead why don't you do it the angular way?

```
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// declare window object so can typescript know it's there.
declare const window: Window;

@Component({
  selector: 'someapp',
  template: `
    <div #wrap class="newData" *ngFor="let title of titles">
      {{title}}
    </div>

    <div id="status">
      {{heights.implode('|')}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public titles: string[] = [];
  public postTitle: string;
  public heights: number[] = [];
  public numberincrem: number = 0;
  // instead of using document to fetch the elements directly from the dom use ViewChild to get the element the Angular way.
  @ViewChild('wrap') public wrap: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.yHandler();
  }

  /// ... declare and define onInit

  public yHandler() {
    // use let instead of var for better variables scoping.
    let contentHeight = this.wrap.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    let yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    let y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if (y >= contentHeight) {
      // use concat to enforce new reference for title array to make it easier on change detection to detect the changes.
      this.titles = [].concat(this.titles, [this.postTitle]);
    }
    this.heights = [].concat(this.heights, [contentHeight]);
  }
}
```